# How to call an Azure Compute Rest API using the Azure Portal in a Function?

Tags: c#, azure

I am writing a pair of functions to turn on/off a Virtual Machine running on Azure.  Currently I am writing the "shut down" function but I am having trouble calling the Rest API.  More specifically, I am trying to call [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/poweroff).

I have created a Timer based function in c# and I have an if statement set to trigger when it hits a certain time.  I have tested this functionality and it works as intended.  Unfortunately I do not know how to do the API call for the rest API.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Add a minimal code example for example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using the Azure Management libraries. They make using the API much easier.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/csharp